# I am getting error when I am using Beanshell Sampler with script in jmeter as Could not initialize class

Tags: java, junit, jmeter, beanshell

My code is

```
import com.ilume.jti.test.controller.romania.*;

RomaniaRoutingControllerTest obj = new RomaniaRoutingControllerTest();
```

but i got following error

> Response code: 500 Response message:
>   org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method:
>   eval  Could not initialize class 
>   com.ilume.jti.test.controller.romania.RomaniaRoutingControllerTest

I have add directory path of my test project, .jar file of test project and  add bsh-2.0.jar in user plan in jmeter. i use jameter version 3.1

can some one help me to solve above error

Comment: where did you kept the `*.jars` related to `romania`? Did you restart the JMeter after that? try importing the class instead of everything i.e., `import com.ilume.jti.test.controller.romania.RomaniaRoutingControllerTest`? Did you use BeanShell Sampler? what is the JMeter version? please add all these details to your question.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter 3.1 comes with [bsh-2.0b5.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.beanshell/bsh/2.0b5) so you don't need to add anything. All you need to do is:

1. To put the .jar containing `RomaniaRoutingControllerTest` class to the "lib/ext" folder of your JMeter installation
2. Add dependency .jar files (if any) to "lib" folder of your JMeter installation
3. Restart JMeter to pick the jar up

If you still be receiving errors after completing the above steps amend your script as follows:

```
debug();
import com.ilume.jti.test.controller.romania.*;

try {
    RomaniaRoutingControllerTest obj = new RomaniaRoutingControllerTest();
}
catch (Throwable ex) {
    log.error("Initializing RomaniaRoutingControllerTest failure", ex);
    throw ex;
}
```

and provide the output from both JMeter Console and *jmeter.log*. See [How to Debug your Apache JMeter Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) article for more information in regards to how to troubleshoot your JMeter tests.